# RAD (eclipse Based) shows a compiler error even after solving it

Tags: compiler-errors, rad

I am working on a J2EE web application. The servlet I am modifying had a method in it that took two parameters. I added a third parameter to the method and adjusted the method calls accordingly. As each call was adjusted the red markings indicating an error disappeared. All except one. The red markings would not disappear and when they did finally disappear after changing the parameter types, the error won't disappear in my problems view. When trying to call the servlet from the browser the error prevents proper running.

The error in the problems view says: "The method writeHeader(PrintWriter, String, boolean) in the type ExportPro__Servlet is not applicable for the arguments (PrintWriter, String)

This what the call to the method is: writeHeader(out, status, booleanVariable);

This is the method header: public void writeHeader(PrintWriter out, String status, boolean bV)

When I ctrl+click on the call it takes me to the method, so we know its calling the write method. There are no other similar methods in the class.

Thank you

Comment: no code, no stacktrace, nothing.... impossible to give useful tips.

Comment: I thought I gave the relevant code.

Comment: When I deleted the line that had the function call the error in the problems view disappeared. When I undid the delete and saved the error did not re-appear in the problems view. This suggests a bug in the problems view or compiler checking. Now that the project is clear of these errors I shouldn't get any errors when running the app. But lo and behold, even after a server restart I get the same error as before doesn't that indicate that some old file is being saved, or it is not looking at my current file. Also none of my new System.out statements are outputting anything to the console.